Names for 3d tensile structure
A naive natural language description might be 'pole supported by tent-like 3d wire net' for the depicted playground climbing arrangement made of rope with a pole in the center.
Is there a more precise technical term for such a 3d tensile network structure that would help with finding existing research on structural properties like required strength for the wires etc?
(playground equipment manufacturer's product page calls it 'Super Spacenet')


Have you checked out "tensegrity?"

@fred_dot_u Many thanks for reminder—how could I have forgotten to look at Buckminster Fuller in this context!

@fred_dot_u I don't think this is tensegrity

Technically speaking, it may not be tensegrity, but there are common factors that may be of value to the OP, hence the suggestion.

I doubt there will be research on the properties of this, but any basic FEA software could be used to do a stress analysis of the structure. Apart from geometry and materials, you would also need to know pretension in the ropes. The "load cases" can be very variable, but you could just add forces representing weights of people to random places and do more analyses like this. Number of the forces could be based on upper limit of simultaneous users (I guess there should be such limit for a structure like this on a sign next to it).
